# Is Kpop in English still Kpop?

Tags: genre, pop, k-pop

Taking for example, BTS song "Dynamite" or "Permission to Dance". While BTS is a Korean pop band, neither of these songs include any Korean. So are they still considered KPop? Or just pop?

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster defines K-pop as follows:

> popular music originating in South Korea and encompassing a variety of
> styles

Hence, the language used does not really matter; It could be in German, and if it originated in South Korea, it would be considered K-pop.

So, yes, per this definition, the songs you named would be considered K-pop.